# Mongoose, how to iteratively add an array of subDocs from an array

Tags: node.js, mongoose

The question title is probably a little less precise than I'd like, but it identifies the spirit of the pattern I'm trying to implement.

An example may be the easiest way to describe this pattern.

**Code Example**

```
//SUBDOCS.js
/*jslint node:true */
"use strict";
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var subDocs = {
    types: {
        images:  new Schema({
            url: {type: String, required: true}
        }),
        colors: new Schema({
            name: {type: String, required: true},
            description: {type: String, required: true}
        }),
        addons: new Schema({
            name: {type: String, required: true},
            description: {type: String, required: true},
            price: {type: Number, required: true}
        })
    }
};

subDocs.keys = function () {
    return Object.keys(this.types);
};

module.exports = subDocs;


//PRODUCT.js
... //Condensed for this example, all requires etc. invoked...
subDocs = require("../models/plugins/product/sub_docs"),
subDocTypes = subDocs.keys(),

var ProductSchema = new Schema({});

subDocTypes.forEach(function (element, index, array) {
    ProductSchema.add({name: element, type: [subDocs.types[element]]});
});
```

Execution returns with an error message:

```
Did you try nesting Schemas? You can only nest using refs or arrays.
```

Thus the question becomes: is there a better way to invoke add in this context, it seems to trip up with types of array.

**Key requirements:**

- Runtime introspection of the `SubDocs` object such that feature
  construction is done via editing the `subDocs.js` file
- Ability to add members of the `subDocs` object to the `ProductSchema` as arrays
  of their respective subdocument type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to add a path to a schema an object is required as the only argument to Schema.add();

In the example above:

```
array.forEach(function (element, index, array) {
    var initializer = {};
    initializer[element] = [subDocs.types[element]];

    ProductSchema.add(initializer);
});
```